# How to drag and drop the records using lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-apps

I need to drag and drop the records in contact object. for example i am having 10 records in contact object.when i drag the 6th record to 4th record, need to replace the 6th record to 4th and 4th record to 5th and 5th record to 6th places.i am usin g below code but i am not getting exact position of the records and need to save the data with changed position in salesforce database.If refresh the lightning component need to show changed position of the records please check below code.

Lightning Application

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
     <c:ConDragandDrop objName="contact" objFields="['Name', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Email', 'Phone','Countvalue__c']"/>
</aura:application>
```

Lightning component

```
<aura:component controller="ConDragandDropController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="objName" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="objFields" type="String[]"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="ContactData" type="ConDragandDropController.Contactwrap"/>
    <div class="slds-page-header">
        <div class="slds-media">
            <div class="slds-media__figure">
                <span class="slds-icon_container" title="Description of icon when needed">
                    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:kanban" variant="bare" size="small"/>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-media__body">
                <h1 class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate slds-align-middle" title="Contact Records">Contact Records</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div style="padding:0.5rem;">
         <div class="stageContainer" style="width:100%">
            <ul ondrop="{!c.drop}" ondragover="{!c.allowDrop}" class="slds-has-dividers_around-space dropZone" style="height:100%;overflow-y:auto;">
                   <aura:iteration var="objRecord" items="{!v.ContactData.records}">

                        <li class="slds-item slds-m-around_small" draggable="true" ondragstart="{!c.drag}" id="{!objRecord.Id}">
                            <article class="slds-tile slds-tile_board">
                                <h3 class="slds-truncate" title="{!objRecord.Name}">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="{!c.doView}">
                                        <span class="slds-truncate" id="{!objRecord.Id}">{!objRecord.Name}</span>
                                    </a>
                                </h3>
                                <div class="slds-tile__detail slds-text-body_small">
                                    <p class="slds-text-heading_medium">First Name: ${!objRecord.FirstName}</p>
                                    <p class="slds-truncate" title="{!objRecord.FirstName}">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="{!c.doView}">
                                            <span class="slds-truncate" id="{!objRecord.LastName}">{!objRecord.LastName}</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </p>

                                </div>
                            </article>
                        </li>

                </aura:iteration>
            </ul>
        </div>    
    </div>   
</aura:component>
```

controller.js

```
({
     doInit: function(component, event, helper) {

          var action = component.get("c.getContactwrap");

          action.setParams({
            "objName":component.get("v.objName"),
            "objFields":component.get("v.objFields")
         });

         action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();

            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                console.dir(response.getReturnValue());
                component.set("v.ContactData", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    doView: function(component, event, helper) {
        var editRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
        editRecordEvent.setParams({
            "recordId": event.target.id
        });
        editRecordEvent.fire();
    },
    allowDrop: function(component, event, helper) {
        event.preventDefault();
    },

    drag: function (component, event, helper) {
        event.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
    },

    drop: function (component, event, helper) {

        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        var tar = event.target;
        while(tar.tagName != 'ul' && tar.tagName != 'UL')
        tar = tar.parentElement;
        tar.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
       event.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

apex controller

```
public class ConDragandDropController{


      @AuraEnabled
       public static Contactwrap getContactwrap(String objName, String[] objFields) {

           String query = 'SELECT Id, ';
           for(String s:objFields){
               query += s+' ,';
           }
           query = query.removeEnd(',');
           query += ' FROM ' + objName;
           System.debug('qq  ' + query);

           return new Contactwrap(Database.query(query));
       }


       public class Contactwrap{
           @AuraEnabled
           List<sObject> records {get;set;}

           public Contactwrap(List<sObject> recs){
               this.records = recs;
           }
       }


}
```

can anybody help me on this

Answer (score 3):

In Lightning, we don't manually move elements around (e.g. `tar.appendChild(document.getElementById(data))`). Instead, we reorder the data, and the platform takes care of it for us. The design pattern you have isn't optimal, but for sake of keeping it simple, here's the modified drop function you'd use:

```
({
drop: function (component, event, helper) {
    var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    // Find the record ID by crawling up the DOM hierarchy
    var tar = event.target.closest('[id]');
    var contactData = component.get("v.ContactData");
    var index1, index2, temp;
    // Find the index of each item to move
    contactData.records.forEach((v,i)=>{if(v.Id===data) index1 = i; if(v.Id===tar.id) index2 = i;});
    if(index1<index2) {
        // Lower index to higher index; we move the lower index first, then remove it.
        contactData.records.splice(index2+1, 0, contactData.records[index1]);
        contactData.records.splice(index1, 1);
    } else {
        // Higher index to lower index; we remove the higher index, then add it to the lower index.
        temp = contactData.records.splice(index1, 1)[0];
        contactData.records.splice(index2, 0, temp);
    }
    // Trigger aura:valueChange, component will rerender
    component.set("v.ContactData", contactData);
    event.preventDefault();
}
})
```

There's no real error checking here, so you might want to take care of situations like when a user drops on to an area that isn't covered by a DOM element that has an ID.

Comment: Thank you for your response.Now drag and drop is working fine. but when i refresh the lightning component the records get back to original position, not getting changed position.

Comment: @TestuserADG You need to save the data somewhere if you expect to use it later. That wasn't part of the original question.

Comment: Thank you for your response but i need to save the changed order wise records to display the records while refresh also. i had updated my question.can you please check and give me a solution.

Comment: @TestuserADG Please avoid editing the question to invalidate answers. If you have a new question, please ask a new question.